# Is sysprep /shutdown sufficient in this case

Tags: windows, sysprep, clonezilla, cloning, sysadmin

In our environment, we manage college computer labs with 30-40 devices each. Our current workflow involves creating a Windows image on a physical machine, **sysprepping** the image with the **/reboot** switch, and then cloning it using **Clonezilla** software.

Upon the first boot with the new image, we **sysprep** all machines in the lab once again with the **/reboot** switch. This additional **sysprep** step is necessary to remove image-specific information, particularly security identifiers, for proper domain integration, as per information found online.

I'm exploring an alternative approach: using the **/shutdown** switch before cloning the image. The idea is that during the first boot with the new image, the second part of the **sysprep** process would kick in and supposedly handle the removal of all **SIDs** and image-specific information.

I have a few questions:

Will this approach work?
Has anyone tried using the **/shutdown** switch instead of **/reboot** in a similar setup?
At which stage of the **sysprep** process does the generalization part occur?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit, and then create a lite touch image. In MDT you should be able to create a image capture task and create and iso for that which automates the steps of creating a sysprepped image. You can integrate that with WDS and then do the capture using PXE https://gal.vin/posts/2022/build-capture-windows-10-22h2/

you can actually image as a “refresh” by kicking off litetouch.vbs from \Server\Share$\Scripts.

Doing a sysprep is essential.

You could also create an PowerShell script as a startup script which does the sysprep. I usually use sysprep /generalize

Comment: Thank You, but my question was very specific. I'm not going to use MDT/WDS setup, because it is not suitable in our situation.